# Ext JS: Populate many-to-many model from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, many-to-many

I am using Ext JS 6 and am trying to populate models `User` and `Roles` using a many-to-many relation from the JSON below.

How would I configure this in Ext JS?

*NOTE: The first root element, `UserNames` is a list of all users. The second root element, `UsersInRoles`, is a list of roles and the users in the roles. Note that a role may not contain any users, and a user may not be a member of any role.*

```
{
    "UserNames": [
      "userName001",
      "userName002",
      "username003",
      "username004"
    ],
    "UsersInRoles": [
      {
        "Role": "Administrators",
        "UserNames": [
          "userName001"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Role": "Approvers",
        "UserNames": []
      },
      {
        "Role": "Readers",
        "UserNames": [
          "userName002",
          "userName004"
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```